# Django reset password via SMS

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I'm working on a Django app, and I would like to authenticate users using their phone numbers, I also would like users to be able to reset their passwords via SMS, is there a way to do it, I can't seem to find anything referencing password reset via SMS in Django, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When the user requests a password reset, your server must generate a unique token (create a model for storing tokens) and send it to the main device associated with the requesting user via a text message, then the user sends it back to the server and the token can be verified, if it is not valid every existing token associated with the user must be invalidated, tokens must also have a quick expiration (like 3 minutes). You can use a third party service such as AWS Pinpoint (with boto3) or Twilio to send text messages